# Apache Tomcat unexpectedly gracefully stops after a POST

Tags: java, json, tomcat

I have a strange tomcat behaviour after posting a request in Json format.

Tomcat shutdown without any exception and/or error

This is the extract of the log file

```
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.470 FINE [http-nio-8082-exec-1190] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke Security checking request POST /xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.470 FINE [http-nio-8082-exec-1190] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints No applicable constraints defined
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.470 FINE [http-nio-8082-exec-1190] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke Not subject to any constraint
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.486 FINE [http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch.countUpOrAwait Counting up[http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] latch=204
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.580 FINE [http-nio-8082-exec-1190] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill Before fill(): parsingHeader: [false], parsingRequestLine: [false], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [319], byteBuffer.limit(): [319], end: [319]
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.580 FINE [http-nio-8082-exec-1190] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.populateReadBuffer Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@6b17f64e:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@4d13a076:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xx.xx.xx.xx:8082 remote=/192.168.99.12:53693]], Read from buffer: [0]
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.580 FINE [http-nio-8082-exec-1190] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@6b17f64e:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@4d13a076:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xx.xx.xx.xx:8082 remote=/xx.xx.xx.xx:53693]], Read direct from socket: [255]
02-Jul-2022 18:50:10.580 FINE [http-nio-8082-exec-1190] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill Received [{"Email":"xxxxx@gmail.com","Fields":[{"Id":1,"Description":"nome","Value":"xxxxxx"},{"Id":2,"Description":"cognome","Value":"xxxxxxx"},{"Id":8,"Description":"paese","Value":"Italia"},{"Id":27,"Description":"compleanno","Value":"yyyy-mm-dd"}]}]
02-Jul-2022 18:50:13.940 FINE [http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch.countUpOrAwait Counting up[http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] latch=205
02-Jul-2022 18:50:17.909 FINE [http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch.countUpOrAwait Counting up[http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] latch=206
02-Jul-2022 18:50:18.252 FINE [http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch.countUpOrAwait Counting up[http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] latch=207
02-Jul-2022 18:50:18.956 FINE [http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch.countUpOrAwait Counting up[http-nio-8082-Acceptor-0] latch=208
02-Jul-2022 18:58:57.810 FINE [Thread-17] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardServer[-1]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
02-Jul-2022 18:58:57.815 FINE [Thread-17] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardServer[-1]] to [STOPPING]
02-Jul-2022 18:58:57.816 FINE [Thread-17] org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.destroyMBeans Destroying MBeans for Global JNDI Resources
02-Jul-2022 18:58:57.822 FINE [Thread-17] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardService[Catalina]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
02-Jul-2022 18:58:57.822 INFO [Thread-17] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]

[2022-07-02 18:58:44] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1032) [ 8012] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 4, dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 0, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0.
[2022-07-02 18:58:53] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1032) [ 8012] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 4, dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 0, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0.
[2022-07-02 18:58:54] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1032) [ 8012] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 4, dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 0, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0.
[2022-07-02 18:58:54] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1032) [ 8012] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 4, dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 0, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0.
->>>>>> [2022-07-02 18:58:57] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1032) [ 8012] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 3, dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 3000, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0.
[2022-07-02 18:58:57] [info] ( prunsrv.c:1132) [ 4112] Stopping service...
[2022-07-02 18:58:57] [debug] ( javajni.c:414 ) [ 4112] Loaded JVM DLL 'C:\Program Files\JAVA\bin\server\jvm.dll', home ''.
[2022-07-02 18:58:57] [debug] ( javajni.c:419 ) [ 4112] JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs...
[2022-07-02 18:58:57] [debug] ( javajni.c:1003) [10616] argv[0] = stop
```

JSON payload:

```json
[
 {"Email":"xxxxx@gmail.com","Fields":
 [
  {"Id":1,"Description":"nome","Value":"xxxxxx"},
  {"Id":2,"Description":"cognome","Value":"xxxxxxx"},
  {"Id":8,"Description":"paese","Value":"Italia"},
  {"Id":27,"Description":"compleanno","Value":"yyyy-mm-dd"}
 ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a `curl` describing how you POST your JSON? (or whatever language you coded in)

Comment: ...and the code that handles the upload. Tomcat doesn't shutdown upon random post requests, you'd have to trigger something else, e.g. from within the handler for your request.